# Form to add products to the database on asp.net Mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Its my first time with asp.net MVC 2. Im came from asp.net webforms.

I would like to know how to build a form to add products (for instance) to a database with client and server validation.

Do you have any url useful that explains this?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards.
Josema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking through [Jon Galloway's MVC Music Store](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/05/12/introducing-the-mvc-music-store-mvc-2-sample-application-and-tutorial.aspx), it's a demo application that might help you. Otherwise the MVC2 articles on [Scott Guthrie's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/) will also give you the basics.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. There are many tutorials out there on how to perform this. For example as far as validation is concerned you might look at [DataAnnotations](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) which allow you to annotate your view models with attributes which will be used to perform server side and client side validation (if you enable it). For more advanced scenarios you could also take a look at [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).